# Would "this summer" in German be in the genitive case?

Tags: grammatical-case, article

If I were to say "Sie haben einen großen Teil in Ihre eigene Sicherheit [this] Sommer", would I be correct in assuming that the correct German word for "this" in this case is the Genitive "dieses"?

This is a rather long sentence, and I believe "[this] Sommer" would be an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "haben". So what case should I use to determine the article?

Comment: @David Vogt No it does not. I need to know what case to use for an adverbial phrase.

Comment: The accepted answer correctly says that the case is accusative, not genitive.

Comment: The clause is incomplete (verb missing). To solve the conundrum, is it the summer's safety or the person's safety during summer ?

Comment: @RHa What answer?

Comment: @Naomi The accepted answer to the question linked by David Vogt.

Comment: @Naomi The person asking the linked question used the term *complement*, but if you look at the examples, they're about adverbial phrases.

Comment: @David Vogt You're right. Thank you! I'll use accusative and see what happens

Comment: It will not explode under your fingers :-)